# Azure edgeAgent not in running state on Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I deploy around 20 IoT Edge devices using automation script ARM/azure cli commands. These edge devices are nothing but VMs. I provision the edge Devices by specifying cloud-init config in VM ARM template. However out of 20, around 3-4 devices somehow have edge Agent in N/A state.

I checked the logs on the respective VMs, iotedge list shows edgeAgent is in running state. But I do see some errors in the edgeAgent logs. Attaching the screenshot.

[iotedge logs edgeAgent output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0r2s.jpg)

Another thing I notice is, on the portal when I navigate to an edgeDevice whose status is N/A, and click on Troubleshoot->Restart Edge Agent , the edgeAgent comes to correct state. But I cannot do this manually for all offline devices. Can somebody help me with the root cause, as to why this is happening in few devices and few devices are all fine.

Comment: Adding question here posted on Q&A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/432463/azure-edgeagent-in-na-status-on-azure-portal-for-4.html

Comment: Link to azure github query: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/5106

Comment: Can you add the logs from "iotedge check" and "iotedge list"?